# doctrine/dbal not installing on live server

Tags: laravel-5, amazon-ec2, doctrine, dbal

When I am issuing command ' composer require doctrine/dbal' on inuc aws ec2 instance. This is freezing screen. Working on laravel 5.7, php > 7.1.
This is stop at  'Updating Dependencies (including require-dev)' line, and not go ahead, no error shows. Please see image attached and suggest solution.

[image]

Comment: Have you verified the EC2 instance has access to the internet? (Security groups and such?)